# Problem with R Package Rgdal and writing MapInfo File

Tags: r, mapinfo, ogr, rgdal, tab

I have a problem using "writeOGR" with the R Package Rgdal.
The strange thing is, that this worked just a few weeks ago, but when I tried to start the R script today, it didn't work.

The Error is: "Error in writeOGR(dat, dsn = "Zones.tab", layer = "Zones", driver = "MapInfo File") : Failed to create feature"

The MapInfo Files are stored, but they are empty (just the column Names are there).

I wrote this, so you guys can have a look. Same Error when I start the code:

```
library(rgdal)
setwd("G:/Löschen")

(dat <- data.frame(Number=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                    East=c(371008,371124,371346,371276,371051,371344),
                    North=c(5720763,5720567,5720761,5720493,5720506,5720490),
                    BW=c(320,350,300,380,275,390)))

coordinates(dat) <- ~East+North

proj4string(dat) <- "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

writeOGR(dat, dsn = "Zones.tab", layer = "Zones", driver = "MapInfo File")
```

Comment: Have you tried leaving the ".tab" file extension off? You are specifying a driver so may not need an extension.

Comment: Yes, Zones.tab will be a directory. Use "." For current directory. Also  fwiw there's are dsn creation options for FORMAT=MIF for that variant.

Comment: I trieed it without .tab extension and it doesn't work either.

I also tried MIF Format - same Problem. When I use the MID Format there is no Error Masage, but I can`t use this Format.

Exporting the Data as ESRI Shape works, but thats not what I

Comment: In **writeOGR{rgdal}** documentation, there is an inline comment which says *#For GDAL >= 2, the TAB driver may need a BOUNDS layer option*. It would suggest an option `layer_options = "BOUNDS"` (or something like this) but it seems this has not been implemented yet in **rgdal**. A possible workaround is; (1) Save your data as ESRI Shapefile by `writeOGR()`, then (2) `library(gdalUtils) ogr2ogr()` to convert it to `Zones.tab`... if it is ok to use other packages.

Answer (score 2):

MapInfo file export using `writeOGR` never worked for me even with clean ESRI source files exported by `writeOGR`.

There is a handy package called `sf`, which writes out MapInfo files. Unlike `gdalUtils::ogr2ogr` it does not rely on an external application, which is not possible to install on the shinyapps.io server, for example.

To save your example in MapInfo format, execute the following:

```
library(sf)
st_write(st_as_sf(dat), dsn = "Zones", layer = "Zones", driver = "MapInfo File")
```

One perhaps undesirable side effect is the creation of a sub-folder named after the last part of the `dsn` so you'll end up with a path like this:

G:\Löschen\Zones\Zones.TAB

I've checked the resulting files in MapInfo Professional 8 and everything looks correct:

[image]

[image]